# How to authenticate Given blogger uri in windows phone 8.1 using http request

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, blogger

I find the ulrs to get posts from google blogger in this url

https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/using but there is no code to how to use the urls

I used this below code to get blogger details

```
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, new Uri("https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/4310477689444728962/posts"));
```

I am stopped here i don't know what is the next process.. please help me to get/post feeds from blogger.

Answer (score 0):

Short of writing the entire program.. you can start here:

If you're trying to OAuth : [Google: API Client Library for .NET](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth)

Pay attention to the Windows Phone 8.1 example.

---

You can also read up on REST Windows Phone 8.1 examples.